# $\forall a>0$ $f(x)=f(y)\Leftrightarrow f(x+a)=f(y+a)$ implies: $\forall b$, $f(x)=f(y)\Leftrightarrow f(x+b)=f(y+b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

$a,x,y$ are two dimensional vectors.

$x> y$ means that both elements of $x$ is greater than $y$.

$f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous and strictly increasing function.

Def: Strictly increasing means that if $x>y$ then $f(x)>f(y)$

Given this condition: if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $\forall a>0$, we have $f(x+a)=f(y+a)$.

> Could we prove (or disprove) that function $f$ satisfies the following stronger condition:
>
> For any  $b\in\mathbb R^2$, $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $f(x+b)=f(y+b)$.

Which is equivalent to: $f(x)=g(c\cdot x)$ where $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is an increasing function and $c$ is a constant vector.

Comment: If we drop the requirement for ""strictly increasing", then $f(x)\neq g(c\cdot x)$.

Comment: The statement in your  title  is  a tautology. It does not require any proof.

Comment: Clarification: if $x = (x_1,x_2)$ and $y = (y_1,y_2)$, does $x > y$ mean that $x_1 > y_1$ and $x_2>y_2$, or that $x_1,x_2$ are larger than both entries of $y$?

Comment: @NoahCaplinger comment made me realize that is the notion of strictly increasing even defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? I think you need to define an order on the domain in order to get a strictly increasing function.

Comment: @NoahCaplinger Your first part is correct. $x_i>y_i$

Comment: @SagarM Hi, in two dimensions, a function is increasing if $x_1>x_2$ and $y_1>y_2$ implies $f(x_1,y_1)>f(x_2,y_2)$

Comment: This order is not well defined.How would you order $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ ? They cannot be ordered with respect to this definition. And a monotonic function is defined only on ordered sets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

Comment: @SagarM Hi, I am using the definition in the question rather than the one in wikipedia. In the question an increasing 2-variable function only requires that $x>y$ implies $f(x)>f(y)$. If $x$ and $y$ are incomparable then no requirements are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to prove this for $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$. $f(x)$ is strictly increasing,
$$\forall x \forall y: x>y \iff  f(x)>f(y)  $$
Hence, 
$$f(x) = f(y) \iff x=y $$
Now,
$$\forall b, x+b = y+b$$
Hence,
$$f(x+b) = f(y+b)$$

Comment: This is a good start! Any ideas to generalize this so we could work togather?